# How How to fix fakes generation with StubX509Certificate2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-fakes, shim

I cannot compile a unit test project which uses Microsoft fakes. When attempting to do so I am presented with the following error.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0115  'StubX509Certificate2.GetCertHash(HashAlgorithmName)': no suitable method found to override [C:\path\ServerAPI.UnitTest\obj\Debug\Fakes\s\f.csproj] ServerAPI.UnitTest  C:\path\ServerAPI.UnitTest\f.cs 137304  Active

I'm using visual studio 2019 (enterprise) and am targeting .NET 4.6.2. I'm unsure why this happens and have tried adding the following code to mscorlib.fakes.

```
<StubGeneration>
<Remove FullName="System.Security.Cryptography"/>
</StubGeneration>
```

Even after removing the fake assembly references and .fakes configuration files, I am still receiving this error.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. It was solved with the following fakes file:

```xml
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="System" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <!-- Prevent the following errors:
    error CS0115: 'StubX509Certificate2.GetCertHash(HashAlgorithmName)': no suitable method found to override
    error CS0115: 'StubX509Certificate2.GetCertHashString(HashAlgorithmName)': no suitable method found to override
    -->
    <Remove Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography"/>
  </StubGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Comment: I had to add it to both `System.fakes` and `mscorlib.fakes` files

Comment: This wasn't exactly the fix for me, but got me in the right direction. I also have `System.fakes` and `mscorlib.fakes`, my `mscorlib.fakes` had: 

    <StubGeneration> 
        <Clear />
    </StubGeneration>

 But, I had nothing about `StubGeneration` for `System.fakes`; so I added the same to it and that resolved the issue for me. I'm only using Shims in the tests, not any Stubs at this point. If you are using Stubs this probably won't work for you.